# Conditionals within Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

This is for using conditionals with Firebase Functions (node.js). I am a total noob when it comes to Javascript so please bear with me. I am trying to send push notifications with different payload (sound) depending on the category of the food ordered. I tried the following code but no notifications are sent. If I removed the if-else conditionals then notifications are sent. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The code compiled fine. Thanks guys. The log showed "ReferenceError: payload is not defined
    at admin.database.ref.once.then.allToken (/user_code/index.js:60:58)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)"

```
exports.sendRequestNotification = functions.database.ref('/Requests/{id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const snapShot = snap.val();
    console.log(snapShot);


     if (snap.child("RequestItemCategory").val() === 1) {
     const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Food Ordered',
            body: 'Seat Number: ' + snap.child("Seat").val() + '   Request Item: ' + snap.child("RequestItem").val(),
            sound: 'food.wav'
        }
       };
     } else {     
     const payload = {
         notification: {
            title: 'New Request Received',
            body: 'Seat Number: ' + snap.child("Seat").val() + '   Request Item: ' + snap.child("RequestItem").val(),
            sound: 'drinks.wav'
       }
      };
     }

    return admin.database().ref('/Tokens').once('value').then(allToken => {
        const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
        console.log(token);
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
    });

});
```

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen. Thanks for the edit. I added the error message from the log. Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A const is only visible within the block where it was declared.  You're declaring two different const payload vars embedded in a block that's not accessible to where you're trying to use it.  You'll need to declare it like this instead:

```
let payload;

if (...) {
    payload = ...
} else {
    payload = ...
}
```

Then you can use payload immediately after the conditional, because it will be in scope for your call to the admin SDK.